# 2D Rotation Array

Tags: php, arrays, math

I need help converting this code from this thread: [How to Rotate a 2D Array of Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646468/how-to-rotate-a-2d-array-of-integers)

to PHP arrays.

```
int [,] newArray = new int[4,4];


for (int i=3;i>=0;--i) {
    for (int j=0;j<4;++j) {
        newArray[j,3-i] = array[i,j];
    }
}
```

Also, will this code work if the blocks are off-center?

Comment: What do you mean by off-center?

Answer (score 0):

Without putting any thought into this at all, "jagged arrays" are pretty much identical to "rectangular arrays" (which PHP doesn't support), so use em:

```
$newArray = array(array())

for($i=3; $i >= 0; --$i) {
    for($j=0; $j < 4; ++$j) {
        $newArray[$j][3-$i] = $oldArray[$i][$j];
    }
}
```