# Rotate array clockwise

Tags: c#, arrays, math

Lets start out with an simple 16 x 16 array of ints.
How would I insert the 'SomeValue' into the array in a 90 degree clockwise order.

```
int[] image = new int[16 * 16];

for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
    {
        int someValue = x * y;

        // This is the line I think is wrong
        image[x + (y * 16)] = someValue; 
    }
}
```

The result should be like the Rotated Array below.

> Normal order:
>   0, 1, 2,
>   3, 4, 5,
>    6, 7, 8,
>
> Rotated Clockwise:
>   6, 3, 0,
>   7, 4, 1,
>   8, 5, 2,

Comment: Your code does not compile, `z` is not declared. You should also simplify your life by using a 2 dimensional array like `int[,] image = new int[16, 16];`

Comment: What's `z`? Do you want to rotate the matrix or insert values into it? Those are two different things.

Comment: Woops, changed the z for a y, Hehe my fault ;)

Comment: now it compiles, what do you expect the code to do? Generate the "Rotated Clockwise" array?

Comment: I want to insert the 'SomeValue' in the image array in a way the image becomes rotated 90 degrees Clockwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2   x
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2   y
= = = = = = = = =
6 3 0 7 4 1 8 5 2   m*(m-1-y)+x
```

for *m=3*.

---

```
const int m = 16;
int[] image = new int[m * m];

for (int x = 0; x < m; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < m; y++)
    {
        int someValue = x * y;

        image[m*(m-1-y)+x] = someValue; 
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about rectangle arrays? what if instead of [16*16] we need to rotate a [5*2] array ?

Comment: For rectangles: `int[] copy = new int[source.Length]; int i = 0; for(int x=0; x < width; x++) { for(int y=height-1; y >= 0; y--) {copy[i++] = source[y * width + x];}}`.  Note that you now assume width becomes height and vice versa in the "copy" array

Answer (score 2):

Follow @Albin Sunnanbos suggestion and use a two-dimensional array. Then have a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646468/how-to-rotate-a-2d-array-of-integers).

Comment: Do you know how to rotate it in a counter clockwise way??

Comment: My sense of symmetry tells me to use `[3-j,i]` instead of `[j,3-i]`. In your case it's 15 instead of 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate the rotated array you can do like this

```
int[,] image = new int[16 , 16];

int current = 0;
for (int x = 15; x >= 0; x--)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
    {
        image[x, y] = current;
        current++;
    }
}

// Output

for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
    {
        Console.Write(image[x,y] + ", ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Well it outputs in a two dimensional array but I can convert that easily :D

Comment: The two dimensional array is not a bug, it is a feature :-)   (it improves the readability and intent of the code)

Comment: You're right! The two dimensional array actual makes it easier :D