# object rotation is not proper - iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, math, rotation, cgcontext

I am facing a typical problem in rotating an object. Description is as given below
I have taken two CGPoint let say point1 and point2
point1 = (50,50)
point2 = (150, 50)
this point will draw a horizontal line.

Now i am drawing a rectangle with that point on it. Width is 100 and height is 10. Angle is 0.
see screen shot 
[image]

works fine
now i change the point let say
point1 = (50,50)
point2 = (50,150)
this point will draw a vertical line.

For rectangle Angle is 90.
 With this point rectangle is not drawing properly
see screen shot
[image]

My code for drawing rectangle is :

```
    CGPoint mid = CGPointMake((point1.x+point2.x)/2, (point1.y+point2.y)/2)
    CGPoint UL = CGPointMake(mid.x + ( Width / 2 ) * cos (A) - ( Height / 2 ) * sin (A) ,  mid.y + ( Height / 2 ) * cos (A)  + ( Width / 2 ) * sin (A));
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, UL.x,routeView.frame.size.height - UL.y);
    CGPoint UR = CGPointMake(mid.x - ( Width / 2 ) * cos (A) - ( Height / 2 ) * sin (A) ,  mid.y + ( Height / 2 ) * cos (A)  - ( Width / 2 ) * sin (A));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, UR.x,routeView.frame.size.height - UR.y);
    CGPoint BR = CGPointMake(mid.x - ( Width / 2 ) * cos (A) + ( Height / 2 ) * sin (A) ,  mid.y - ( Height / 2 ) * cos (A)  - ( Width / 2 ) * sin (A));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, BR.x,routeView.frame.size.height - BR.y);
    CGPoint BL = CGPointMake(mid.x + ( Width / 2 ) * cos (A) + ( Height / 2 ) * sin (A) ,  mid.y - ( Height / 2 ) * cos (A)  + ( Width / 2 ) * sin (A));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, BL.x,routeView.frame.size.height - BL.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, UL.x,routeView.frame.size.height - UL.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Here A is Angle and it is not static, mid is middle point of point1 and point2

for more ref [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644378/drawing-a-rotated-rectangle)

Am I missing something?
Please help me if you have any idea.......

Thanks,

Comment: a is angle which: 0 in first case and 90 in second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess, it's actually rotated about 26 degrees too far, right?

(**90** x 180) / Pi ~= 5156.62 = (360 x 14) + **90** + **26.62**

You rotated it 90 **radians** by mistake.