# How do you rotate a polygon?

Tags: java, polygon

I'm attempting to rotate a polygon around a fixed axis using the rotate method in Graphics2d. However, after each rotation, the bounding box coordinates of the polygon don't seem to be updating--only the graphical representation. How might I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a library method that simply does a graphical transform.  It is working the way it was designed.  To get the new coordinates, you will have to do the math.

EDIT:
Here's a link to another question that has all the math you need.

[Drawing a Rotated Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644378/drawing-a-rotated-rectangle?rq=1)

Comment: That's what I figured. Could you give me some insight regarding the required math?